# NullPointerException When trying to get string element from array

Tags: java

I have an array of strings called "CONSOLES" and a method "getConsoleName", when I try to get the name by index ID, i get a "NullPointerException"

I just want to get the name by using index...

for example:

```
   String myconsole = getConsoleName(0); // myConsole will be "PC"
```

---

this is my code:

```
   public static String[] CONSOLES = {
    "PC",
    "PS4",
    "XBOX ONE",
    "PS VITA"
};

public static String getConsoleName(int ID)
{
    String rtext = "unknown";
    try {
        rtext = CONSOLES[ID];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return rtext;
}
```

I hope you understood me

Comment: There is no array called `CONSOLE`. It is called `CONSOLES`. But I'm surprised this throws a NullPointerException rather than a compilation error. Anyways, your question isn't too clear. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: it looks ok to me. if the index were out of bounds you would get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. maybe the exception is coming from another part of the code. try using e.printStackTrace() rather than System.err.println(e) as it will give you more information, like the line number where the exception occured

Comment: There is no possibility for a NPE in the code you posted, unless you somewhere assign null to `CONSOLES` or call it with `getMachineName((Integer) null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code. Its working fine. no error I am getting output PC

```
public class StackOverFlow {
 public static String[] CONSOLES = {
            "PC",
            "PS4",
            "XBOX ONE",
            "PS VITA"
        };

 public static void main(String arg[]){

    System.out.println(getConsoleName(0));


} 


public static String getConsoleName(int ID)
{
    String rtext = "unknown";
    try {
        rtext = CONSOLES[ID];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return rtext;
}
```

}

If you are getting NullPointerException , please give complete code with main method to see where from it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Better code would be - 
You need to check first if the ID is less than the length of the CONSOLES array

```
   public static String getConsoleName(int ID)
   {
        return (ID < CONSOLES.length ? CONSOLES[ID] : "unknown");
   }
```

If the code is throwing NullPointerException, please paste the logs showing more details on which line

Comment: the error is NullPointerException, not ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Not going to help if `CONSOLES` is `null`. Which I kind of think it must be to produce a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: He has a try-catch inside his method to handle the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException anyway. This answer is not really an answer, to be honest.

Comment: the code does not show the try-catch. How do you find out that it handles ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  if the code in question does not show try-catch

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the CONSOLES won't be null. It is Static String[]. Unless some other code is resetting/setting to null, the CONSOLES it won't be null

Comment: @vlaxmi There is a try-catch in the code in the question. Inside the method.